# Magento 2 express checkout want to disable using product sku?

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, onestepcheckout

In my Magento 2 i have two products with sku's

1. seller-commission-product
2. Austinmer 4 Door

   1. I need to show paypal express checkout for the item sku is **seller-commission-product**  & (this flow is **working fine**)
   2. I don't want to show the paypal express checkout if item sku is **not a** seller-commission-product, i want to **show remaining payment methods as it is** **(Not working)**

Hence i have followed the below procedure.

> app/code/Ewall/Account/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="payment_method_is_active">
<observer name="Ewall_Account_Payment_Methods_For_Active" instance="Ewall\Account\Observer\PaymentMethodAvailable" />
</event>
</config>
```

> app/code/Ewall/Account/Observer/PaymentMethodAvailable.php

```
<?php
namespace Ewall\Account\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{ 
    /**
     * payment_method_is_active event handler.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/stackexchange.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $paymentHelper = $objectManager->get('Ewall\Account\Model\Paymentmethod');
        $activePaymentMethods = $paymentHelper->toOptionArray();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        // retrieve quote items array
        $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        $requiredSku = '';
        foreach($items as $item) 
        {
            $requiredSku = $item->getSku();
        }
        $logger->info("activePaymentMethods===".print_r($activePaymentMethods,true));

        if($requiredSku == 'seller-commission-product')
        {
            if($observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() != 'paypal_express')
            {
                $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
                $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); //This is disabling all payment methods except paypal_express
            }

        }elseif($requiredSku != 'seller-commission-product')
        {

            if($observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() == 'paypal_express')
            {
                $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
                $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); //This is enable all payment methods except paypal_express
            }


        }

    }


}
```

> app/code/Ewall/Account/Model/Paymentmethod.php

```
<?php

namespace Ewall\Account\Model;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use \Magento\Payment\Model\Config;

class Paymentmethod extends \Magento\Framework\DataObject implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_appConfigScopeConfigInterface;
    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    protected $_paymentModelConfig;

    /**
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $appConfigScopeConfigInterface
     * @param Config               $paymentModelConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $appConfigScopeConfigInterface,
        Config $paymentModelConfig
    ) {

        $this->_appConfigScopeConfigInterface = $appConfigScopeConfigInterface;
        $this->_paymentModelConfig = $paymentModelConfig;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $payments = $this->_paymentModelConfig->getActiveMethods();
        $methods = array();
        $myCustomPaymentMethods = array();
        foreach ($payments as $paymentCode => $paymentModel) {

            $myCustomPaymentMethods[]=$paymentCode;

            $paymentTitle = $this->_appConfigScopeConfigInterface
                ->getValue('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
            $methods[$paymentCode] = array(
                'label' => $paymentTitle,
                'value' => $paymentCode
            );
        }

        return $myCustomPaymentMethods;//Here i am returning active payment method codes

    }
}
```

Please suggest me how can fix this? the second flow not working for me. please suggest  me whether this approach is correct or not?